# How to extend expired date access token in Microsoft Graph API example in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft-graph-api

I am using the Microsoft Graph API to generate OAuth 2.0 access token, which expires after 1 Hour. Route being used is:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{Tenant ID}
```

I am passing these values in the query string.

```
{ 
    grant_type: "client_credentials", 
    client_id: APP_ID, 
    client_secret: APP_PASSWORD, 
    scope: "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default", 
}
```

Now, my current implementation I have added recursion in which I added retries before calling a Graph API to extract user details from AD, how to access token expiry date extend using a Microsoft Graph API in C#.

```
public string SelectInterfaceEndPoint(Guid? franchiseRegionUid)
{
     var endPoint = string.Empty;

     try
     {
         using (var cn = new SqlConnection(_systemEnvironment.CommonConnectionString))
         {
             if (_systemEnvironment.IsLiveCommonServer)
             {
                 cn.AccessToken = _systemEnvironment.AzureConnectionToken;
             }

             using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("FranchiseRegion_SelectEndPoint", cn))
             {
                 cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                 if (franchiseRegionUid != null)
                     cmd.Parameters.Add("@FranchiseRegionUid", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier).Value = franchiseRegionUid;

                 cn.Open();

                 using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                 {
                     if (reader.Read())
                     {
                         endPoint = General.DbNullString(reader["InterfaceEndPoint"].ToString());
                     }
                 }

                 cn.Close();
                 cn.Dispose();
             }
         }

         return endPoint;
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         _logMessage.Log(_project, _module, "SelectInterfaceEndPoint", EventLogEntryType.Error, ex, string.Empty, _userId);
         return endPoint;
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

To extend the access token expiration time, `you can request a new token by calling the token endpoint with the same credentials and parameters used to obtain the original token`. The new token that is returned will have a refreshed expiration time.

Note that you will need to have a check in the retry logic that renews the token when you get a `401` from Graph API.
Some Correction: You get access token from `Microsoft Entra ID (Azure AD)` Not Microsoft Graph API.

Here is a code example that demonstrates how to do this using the Microsoft Authentication Library (MSAL) for .NET:

```
// Set up a confidential client application with the app ID and password
ConfidentialClientApplication app = new ConfidentialClientApplication(
    ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["appId"],
    ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["appSecret"],
    new TokenCache(),
    new ConfidentialClientApplicationOptions
    {
        Authority = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}"
    });

// Get a new access token using client credentials flow
var scopes = new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
var result = await app.AcquireTokenForClientAsync(scopes);

// Check if the token is expired
if (result.ExpiresOn <= DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes(5))
{
    // Get a new access token with a refreshed expiration time
    result = await app.AcquireTokenForClientAsync(scopes);
}

// Use the access token to call the Graph API
var client = new GraphServiceClient(new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(
    async (requestMessage) =>
    {
        requestMessage.Headers.Authorization =
            new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result.AccessToken);
    }));

// Make the Graph API call
var user = await client.Users["{userId}"]
    .Request()
    .Select(u => new
    {
        u.DisplayName,
        u.Mail,
        u.UserPrincipalName
    })
    .GetAsync();
```

You can find more information on how to use MSAL to get access tokens for the Microsoft Graph API in the following documentation:

Microsoft Authentication Library (MSAL) for .NET: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-net-overview
Call Microsoft Graph API in a web API using MSAL.NET: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-web-api-call-graph-with-msal
Sample code for using MSAL to call the Microsoft Graph API: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnetcore-daemon-v2